# iOS - ViewController not being released when popped under ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a`UITabBarController` as my main base view controller. Under the first tab, I have a `UINavigationController` which of course has a `rootViewController` associated with it, call it `vcA`. `vcA` has a button which fires a child view controller, `vcB` using the code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PlacesDetailsSegue" sender:senderDictionary];
```

This appears to work, and I see in instruments that new allocations for vcB are occurring. 
When I pop the view controller back to `vcA`, everything looks to work, but it appears that vcB is never released (i.e., dealloc is never called). So every time a go from `vcA->vcB->vcA->vcB`, the memory usage increases and increases.

I have some instance variables inside `vcB`, all of which I set to `nil` in `dealloc`. But since dealloc isn't being fired, they are never actually set to `nil`.

I do have a `[UIView animationWith...]` block which references the frame properties of `self.view`, but I have managed that using the code:

```
__unsafe_unretained BBCategoryViewController *weakSelf = self;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
    animations:^{
        [_feedTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
                         _navBar.frame.size.height,
                         weakSelf.view.frame.size.width, 
                         weakSelf.view.frame.size.height - kMenuBarHeight)
        ];

     }
     completion:nil];
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about finding out what objects are still being retained on a vcB pop?

For reference, my interface extension is:

```
@interface BBCategoryViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UITableView *_feedTableView;
    UIRefreshControl *_refreshControl;
    BBSearchBar *_searchBar;
    MKMapView *_mapView;
    BBNavigationBar *_navBar;
    NSString *_title;
    NSString *_categoryId;
    NSArray *_feedArray;
}
@end
```

and my dealloc (which is never fired) is:

```
-(void)dealloc {

    NSLog(@"Dealloc: BBCategoryViewController\n");
    _feedTableView = nil;
    _refreshControl = nil;
    _searchBar = nil;
    _mapView = nil;
    _navBar = nil;
    _feedArray = nil;

}
```

**UPDATE:** This was actually due to a retain cycle in a child view, and not directly related to the view controllers as I first thought. Dan F led me to the correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387476/passing-a-viewcontroller-to-a-child-view-and-then-back-again-fails-to-release-t), in case anyone runs across something similar.

Comment: Do you actually see this behavior?  The view controller being instantiated every time the segue is performed?

Comment: @DanF: I see an allocation in instruments, yes.

Comment: How are you "popping" back to vcA? Are you using a segue?

Comment: You have a reference cycle. Probably a block.

Comment: we've experienced similar issue couple of weeks ago; we suspected a strong retain-cycle, because the memory was not deallocated after we popped the view controller out from the navigation stack. finally, we found, when the application is just running, the iOS does not release immediately the memory for the view controllers, but when we just put the application to the background, that memory was deallocated properly by the iOS immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your vcB should absolutely be deallocated, and dealloc called when you pop back to vcA. You must either be keeping a strong reference to it somewhere, or you're doing your "pop" incorrectly. If you're doing that with a segue, that could be your problem -- segues should not be used for going backwards (except unwind segues). So either use an unwind segue or use popViewControllerAnimated to go back to vcA. Also, when using ARC, there's no need to set your ivars to nil in dealloc.

Comment: I think you are on to something. Something in the vcB is forcing a strong reference. Are there any tools to help figure out what it is tho? I am using `popViewControllerAnimated` to pop the view.

Comment: @Brett, I don't know of any tools to do that. Is you code so complicated that you can't find that by inspection? Are you using any delegate protocols between these two classes?