# Passing a ViewController to a child view, and then back again fails to release the VC in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, protocols

I have an issue (related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381236/ios-viewcontroller-not-being-released-when-popped-under-arc) SO question). But the root problem is so different than I originally thought, that I need to post it as a new question; but I'll update the previous question to reference this one - if anyone is able to help.

I have a `UINavigationController` which has `vcA` as the `rootViewController`. `vcB` is then pushed onto the navigation stack. `vcB` has a child view which is a `UIView` subclass (call it `BSView`) with some buttons on it. I need to have `vcB` be aware of when the buttons on `BSView` are tapped, so I implemented a `@protocol` as in the `BBView.h` as shown below:

```
@protocol BBViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)buttonAPressed;
-(void)buttonBPressed;
-(void)buttonCPressed;
@end

@interface BBView : UIView {
    id<BBViewDelegate> _delegate;
    NSString *_title;
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withTitle:(NSString *)title 
        andDelegate:(id<BBViewDelegate>)delegate;
@end
```

and the `BBView.m` init method looks like:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withTitle:(NSString *)title 
                                andDelegate:(id<BBViewDelegate>)delegate
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        _delegate = delegate;
        _title = title;
    }
  return self;
}
```

where `delegate` will be `vcB`. And when `buttonA` is pressed, this code is fired:

```
if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonAPressed)]) {
    [_delegate buttonAPressed];
}
```

This *appears* to work fine. All the methods are called as expected. **Here is the problem. When I pop vcB back to vcA, vcB is never released. If vcB is pushed again, then the memory just cycles up. I can repeat this cycling until the app explodes.**

When I don't init `BBView` with any delegate variable (or a `nil` value), the `vcB` memory is released on a navigation pop. But then of course, `vcB` is never made aware of the button taps.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on??? I have been messing with this for a long time now, and I simply can't figure out how to pass in `vcB` as an object to `BBView` and have it release when the navigation is popped back to `vcA`.

Any pointers would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `delegate` pointer is creating a retain loop.  You should declare the `delegate` variable as `__weak` or as a `weak` property

Comment: Wow, that was simple and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also, thanks for posting on my other question. I'll reference this answer in the previous question as well.